# size of Two-dimensional arrays in Java

Tags: java

I want to make a loop on Two-dimensional array in Java.

How I do that? I wrote:

```
    for (int i = 0; i<=albums.size() - 1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<=albums.size() - 1; j++){
```

But it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by it didnt work?

Comment: Are you using arrays or ArrayLists?

Comment: Two dimensional arrays are essentially an array of arrays.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Arrays have a read-only field called `length`, not a method called `size`.  A corrected loop looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < albums.length; i++ ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < albums[i].length; j++) {
        element = albums[i][j];
```

You have to recognize that a 2-D array is just an array whose element type happens to be another array.  So the `i` loop iterates over each element in `albums` (which is an array) and the `j` loop iterates over that child array (with a potentially different size).

A more transparent way would be like this:

```
String[][] albums;

for(int i = 0; i < albums.length; i++ ) {
    String[] childArrayAtI = albums[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < childArrayAtI.length; j++) {
        String element = childArrayAtI[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you are working with Java 1.5+:

```
for(int [] album : albums) {
    for(int albumNo : album) {
        System.out.print(albumNo + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a two-dimensional array looks like this in Java:

```
int[][] albums = new int[10][10];
```

Now, for iterating over it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < albums[i].length; j++) {
        int value = albums[i][j];
    }
}
```